# How to get values from partial view bootstrap modal to update form?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I have a bootstrap modal that handles a single transaction and I'm trying to get the values from the modal then when I press add button then I want the modal to close then do an ajax post to the controller. The controller should handle the collections and single instance of the object not sure it's entirely correct. I added an example dotnetfiddle link to make it easier to share code.

Is it possible to be done with the bootstrap modal for a better user experience?

What I'm trying to achieve:
When you add a transaction by clicking create transaction when you input the date and amount those values should be added to the CustomerTransactions collection and displayed on the form with the current amount of transactions and what they are. I've added an unordered list in the html.

Here is the data structure:

View:
Just the one view with the form, items, html and jQuery and ajax call

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [MinLength(10)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Ask Magic 8 Ball any question:")]
        public string Question { get; set; }

        //See here for list of answers
        public string Answer { get; set; }

        //Ignore the above properties for now
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public SampleTransactionItemViewModel CustomerTransaction { get; set; }
        public List<SampleTransactionItemViewModel> CustomerTransactions { get; set; }
    }

    public class SampleTransactionItemViewModel
    {
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static Random _rnd = new Random();  
        private static List<string> _db = new List<string> { 
            "Yes", "No", "Definitely, yes", "I don't know", "Looks like, yes"
        };

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new SampleViewModel());
        }


        /*[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetAnswer(string question)
        {               
            int index = _rnd.Next(_db.Count);
            var answer = _db[index];
            return Json(answer);
        }*/

        [HttpPost]      
        public ViewResult AddTransactionItem(SampleViewModel model)
        {
            model.CustomerTransactions.Add(model.CustomerTransaction);
            model.CustomerTransaction = null;

            //return PartialView("Modal/TransactionModal", output);
            return View("FraudCheckBankAccountForm", model);
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style type="text/css">

            .field-validation-error {
                color: #ff0000;
            }
            p{
            padding: 10px 0;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h4>Example Adding items to collection dynamically</h4><br>

                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {@class="form-control"})                      
                    </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TransactionModal">
                                Create Transaction
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        Current transactions
                        <!-- Added here dynamically-->
                        Transactions:
                        <ul>
                            <li>TransactionDate: Date here</li>
                            <li>TransactionAmount: Amount here</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                       <br>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success submit">Save</button>

                        <div class="modal fade" id="TransactionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TransactionModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create transaction</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Date</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.CustomerTransaction.TransactionDate, new { @class = "form-control Date", @id = "Transaction_Date", @name = "Transaction.Date", @type ="date" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group NoBottomPad">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Amount</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.CustomerTransaction.TransactionAmount, new { @class = "form-control Amount", @id = "Transaction_Amount", @name = "Transaction.Amount"})
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="hinttext" style="font-size: smaller; text-align: left; margin-left: -10px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom; ">
                            Example
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button class="btn" id="TransactionModalCancelButton" name="TransactionModalCancelButton" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn-default btn" id="AddTransaction" name="AddTransaction" type="button" disabled>Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                }

                <br/><br/>
                <div class="alert alert-warning fade">
                    <img src="http://entechprod.blob.core.windows.net/dotnetfiddle/morpheus.jpg" style="max-width:100%;"/><br/><br/>
                    <strong><span class="alert-content"></span></strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function openAlert(txt) {
                $('.alert-content').text(txt);
                $('.alert').addClass('in');
            }

            function closeAlert() {
                $('.alert').removeClass('in');
            }

            $(function(){
                var answer = '@Model.Answer';

                if(answer && answer != '') 
                    openAlert(answer);

                $('#Question').change(closeAlert);
                $('#Question').keyup(closeAlert);

                // This is the save button
                var save = document.getElementById("AddTransaction");
                var cancel = document.getElementById("TransactionModalCancelButton");

                // This is the text fields
                var date = document.getElementById("Transaction_Date");
                var amount = document.getElementById("Transaction_Amount");

                // This is the transaction list
                var transList = document.getElementById("CustomerTransactions");
                var container = document.getElementById("TransactionResult");

                // Date validation
                $(date).change(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() !== "" && $(amount).val() !== "") {
                        $(save).prop('disabled', false);
                    } else {
                        $(save).prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                });

                // Amount validation
                $(amount).keyup(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() !== "" && $(date).val() !== "") {
                        $(save).prop('disabled', false);
                    } else {
                        $(save).prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                });

                $('.submit').click(function(){
                    if($('form').valid()) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetAnswer", controller="Home"})',
                            data: {Answer: '', Question: $('#Question').val()},
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                success: function(resp) {
                                openAlert(resp);
                        }});
                    }
                    else {
                        closeAlert();
                    }
                });

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also I would like a dynamic list to be added to the view but not sure how to implement it. Check out the dotnetfiddle link below for the code.

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Current transactions
                        <!-- Added here dynamically foreach transaction in transactions-->
                        Transactions:
                        <ul>
                            <li>TransactionDate: Date here</li>
                            <li>TransactionAmount: Amount here</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Current transactions
                        <!-- Added here dynamically-->
                        Transactions:
                        <ul>
                            <li>TransactionDate: Date here</li>
                            <li>TransactionAmount: Amount here</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Link to code: 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/2uG3sv

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery as follow:

1- When click on `add` call `AddTransactionItem` using `$.port`.

2- Hide the model if there is no error.

```
 $('#AddTransaction').click(function () {
        var TransactionDate = $('#Transaction_Date').val();
        var TransactionAmount = $('#Transaction_Amount').val();

        $.post('@Url.Action("AddTransactionItem","Home")', { CustomerTransaction: {TransactionDate: TransactionDate, TransactionAmount: TransactionAmount} })
            .done(function (data) {
                $(".TransactionModal").modal('hide');
            }).fail(
                function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("create", jqXHR.responseText, 'error');
                });

        });
```

3- For return data you can easily return JSON message for example:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddTransactionItem(SampleViewModel model)
        {
            model.CustomerTransactions = new List<SampleTransactionItemViewModel> {model.CustomerTransaction};
           // model.CustomerTransaction = null;
            return Json("any message here");
            //return PartialView("Modal/TransactionModal", output);
           // return View("FraudCheckBankAccountForm", model);
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean using $.post Abdul Hadi

Comment: Also how do I get the data from the controller back to the view e.g. the transaction date and amount?